# SDRUM verse-chorus switch causes JamMan to restart loop

Tags: looper-pedals

I use the SDRUM and JamMan Solo XT in tandem with my electric guitar to accompany a live electric fiddle performance. The SDRUM and JamMan are linked with a jamsync TRS cable. I begin by starting the JamMan, which flashes red until the SDRUM is started. I then play chords on the JamMan for 32 bars while backing the fiddle. When it's time to continue playback, I stomp the JamMan and play fills. If the fiddler stops playing, I take a solo.

Unfortunately, I encounter an intermittent issue where the JamMan loop unexpectedly goes back to the beginning from the middle, especially when I stomp the SDRUM to switch from chorus to verse or vice versa. I've tried two different JamMan pedals, but the problem persists.

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue and if there are any solutions or workarounds available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDRUM sends a MIDI start message to the JamSync'ed JamMan when the SDRUM foot button is pressed. The user is supposed to record a loop for the verse and a loop for the chorus and press the next loop or previous loop switch on the Digitech FS3X switch attached to the JamMan Solo XT at the same time as the SDRUM foot button.  Stupid, but there you go. No hope of a firmware upgrade as the SDRUM is a discontinued product.